# Component key value is missing in props validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `IMovie` interface:

```
export interface IMovie {
  id: number;
  original_title: string;
  poster_path: string;
  release_date: string;
  backdrop_path: string;
}
```

And a component that renders a UL and a map function that loops through each object in an array and for each object it renders the `ResultListItem` component:

```
const ResultListItem = ({movie}: {movie: IMovie}) => {
  const [isHover, setHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <li
      key={movie.id}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}>
      <p>
        <span>{movie.original_title}</span>
        <span>{movie.release_date}</span>
      </p>
      { movie.poster_path !== null ?
        <img src={imagePath + movie.poster_path} alt={movie.original_title}/>:
        <PosterNotFound src={posterNotFound} alt='No poster available' />
      }
      {isHover && <AddMovieToWatchList movie={movie}/>}
    </li>
  );
};

return (
  <ul>
    { orderedList.map((movie: IMovie) => {
      return (
        <ResultListItem key={movie.id} movie={movie} />
      );
    })}
  </ul>
);
```

I'm getting a error:

> 'movie.id' is missing in props validation

on this line :

```
<ResultListItem key={movie.id} movie={movie} />
```

If I chance the props on the `ResultListItem` to:

```
const ResultListItem = (movie) => {}
```

The error is gone, but  I want/need to use prop deconstruction. The error is probably caused by the deconstruction of the `ResultListItem` prop but I can't figure out what the correct syntax would be.

Comment: No, the `key=movie.id` is correct. In this context movie is a result from the `orderedList.map`. In the `ResultListItem` the prop is a `movie.movie` because I pass a movie object in a movie prop in the map. That's why I want to deconstruct the prop.

Comment: It seems like typescript is not sure the variable you are using as `movie` actually has an `id` property. I would check the origin of that variable

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with TypeScript. The interface IMovie is working as expected  and through intillisense I can find the `id` property on the `movie`. I think it's a react issue, also seeing that the error refers to prop validation.

Comment: So, your `ResultListItem` takes an object containing a `movie` property, don't you need to wrap what you are passing in in an object? `movie={{movie}}`